# Tengo problemas para asosiar 4 tablas diferentes con INNER JOIN

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Hola tengo problemas para seleccionar datos de 4 tablas con `inner join`, este es mi código:

```
$registrosBus = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM productos as p INNER JOIN categorias as c on selectCat=id INNER JOIN ofertasusers as o on categoria=category INNER JOIN usersst as u on idUsuer=idUsuer WHERE nameproducto LIKE'%$busqueda%' OR categoria LIKE '%$busqueda%';");

if(mysqli_num_rows($registrosBus)>0)
```

Y luego sale este error:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que la consulta tiene un error.

El **warning** te está diciendo que `$registrosBus` es un booleano (`FALSE`) en vez de ser un `mysqli_result`.

Como mínimo tienes un problema en las referencias usadas para los JOINS, no estas usando los alias que defines y ese campo `id` es ambiguo, seguramente existe en todas las tablas, lo cual dará error.

Prueba usando referencias explicitas en todos los campos usados:

```
 SELECT p.* 
   FROM productos AS p 
  INNER JOIN categorias AS c ON p.selectCat=c.id 
  INNER JOIN ofertasusers AS o ON o.categoria=c.category 
  INNER JOIN usersst AS u ON u.idUsuer=o.idUsuer 
  WHERE p.nameproducto LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR c.categoria LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

> Deberías mostrar la estructura de las tablas para poder verificar
>   estas relaciones